# Downloading files using Header with a JS input

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page that has a JavaScript function that uses Post to send a variable to a php file. The problem is, that I am using "header" to download the file and my JS does not open the PHP script in a new page.

When I open the php file in a new page, it does not receive the needed variable from the JS.

I know it sounds confusing, but I hope my code can shed some light on my problem.

The short version is, I am trying to download a file that is selected by a radiobutton. I use JS to check which radiobutton is checked and then send that to my php file. Which then needs to download the file.

Thank you all in advance.

PHP:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['routenumber'])) {
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
$routenumber = (isset($_POST['routenumber']) ? $_POST['routenumber'] : null);


$directory = ("Users/".$_SESSION['id']."/SavedRoutes/");

$routes = scandir($directory);
sort($routes);
$route = $routes[$routenumber];

$file =("Users/".$_SESSION['id']."/SavedRoutes/".$route);


header("Content-type: application/gpx+xml");
// header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".json_encode($route).".gpx");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=route.gpx");


readfile($file);

}
?>
```

JS:

```
function fuAccountDownloadRoute(){
var i=2;
var SelectedRadio
while (i < routecounter){
    var str1='radio';
    var str2=JSON.stringify(i);
    var result = str1.concat(str2);
    if (document.getElementById(result).checked){
        SelectedRadio = result.slice(5);
    }
    i=i+1;  
}


$.post('accountPage.php',{routenumber:SelectedRadio});
}
```

Comment: header have to be in top of file, mate!

Comment: please include code for: "I open the php file in a new page"

Comment: When I manually open the php file in my browser manually that is @Gavriel

Answer (score 0):

When you open the url: http://localhost/accountPage.php in your browser it makes a GET request. You should change all the $_POST to $_GET in your code if you want to make it possible, and then you can open it like this: http://localhost/accountPage.php?routenumber=3, though it's probably not what you really want.